# Hibernate : Stale state exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am trying to delete an object from the database. Some days back, this error all of a sudden started, and now I am unable to delete. I checked on net, but I cannot find what am I doing wrong and none of the solutions seem to work.

Service layer code :

```
  @Override
    public boolean deleteGroupSection(int sectionId, int mcanvasId) {
        try {
        GroupCanvas groupCanvas = this.groupCanvasService.getCanvasById(mcanvasId);
        Long groupAccountId = this.groupAccountService.getGroupById(groupCanvas.getGroupAccountId()).getGroupId();
            this.groupAttachmentsService.deleteAttachmentsForSection(sectionId,groupAccountId);
        }catch (Exception ignored){}
        this.groupSectionDAO.deleteGroupSection(sectionId,mcanvasId);
        return true;
    }
```

DAO code :

```
 @Override
    public boolean deleteGroupSection(int sectionid, int mcanvasId) {
        Session  session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         GroupSection groupSection = (GroupSection) session.get(GroupSection.class,sectionid);
         session.delete(groupSection);
         session.flush();
         return true;
    }
```

Error code :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1] with root cause
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupSectionDAOImpl.deleteGroupSection(GroupSectionDAOImpl.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

What am I doing wrong. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Check if there is a record with the id `sectionid`. I think there is no.

Comment: @Jens : There is, we have checked it multiple times, there are objects with one-to-many relationships with section, they are also there, and there is cascade.Delete set so we dont get errors when trying to remove parent.

Comment: If there is any config or code required, please let me know.

Comment: Jens seems to be right. Maybe GroupSection could've been deleted in a cascade happening in the previous `groupAttachmentsService.deleteAttachmentsForSection()` call. Try setting the logging categories `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type` to `trace` and examining the sql statements that are executed.

Comment: @WornOutSoles : That method only deletes the Files from disk, nothing else. That is why I am ignoring the exception if file from disk fails to delete or does not exist. If necessary, I can comment out that code, and I have used Log4j.xml in debug mode for org.hibernate, I am pasting the log.

Comment: Have you had a look at the statements while debugging? It's likely that although you're deleting the entity, some other object is holding a reference to it. Are you executing Service.deleteGroupSection() in a @Transactional context?

Comment: @WornOutSoles : This is crazy, as soon as I put  this.groupSectionDAO.deleteGroupSection(sectionId,mcanvasId); on the first line in service layer, the error disappears. I will delete my post then, but I would like to know why.

Comment: Yeah, pretty weird...Does GroupCanvas have a reference to GroupSection?

Comment: @WornOutSoles : GroupCanvas has a one-to-many mapping with GroupSection, i.e one GroupCanvas can have multiple GroupSections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that you were loading a GroupCanvas before and this has a reference to the GroupSection. Then you delete the GroupSection but when the transaction commits GroupCanvas still holds a reference to the deleted GroupSection and you get the StaleStateException.

As you saw, deleting the GroupSection first prevents the GroupCanvas from loading the already deleted GroupSection.

As an alternative, you can also do something like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean deleteGroupSection(int sectionId, int mcanvasId) {
        try {
            GroupCanvas groupCanvas = this.groupCanvasService.getCanvasById(mcanvasId);
            Long groupAccountId = this.groupAccountService.getGroupById(groupCanvas.getGroupAccountId()).getGroupId();
            this.groupAttachmentsService.deleteAttachmentsForSection(sectionId,groupAccountId);
        }catch (Exception ignored){}

        this.groupSectionDAO.deleteGroupSection(sectionId,mcanvasId);

        for(Iterator<GroupSection> it = groupCanvas.getGroupSections().iterator(); it.hasNext();){
            GroupSection gs = it.next();
            if(gs.getId().equals(sectionId)){
                it.remove(gs);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Understanding why it happened was more important to me, I have no issues with the delete line being in the first place, and yes, The above code would not be useful, as it crashes already at deleteGroupSection, so the code is not executed after that.